# Flag in Linear Algebra Visualization in Tikz

Tags: tikz-styles

Could someone help me to code this in Tikz.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! There are tons of examples on this site and on the internet about how to draw such simples shapes. Please tell us more about where your problem is and provide some code to start with. Maybe your problem is to align the drawings?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:
You may want to adjust things a bit
You need to bring the label of V_3 to the front somehow
And change the color
Output:
[image: tikz diagram]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1, every node/.style={scale=1}]
  % Define the 3D view
  \begin{scope}[x={(2cm,0cm)},y={({cos(30)*0.7cm},{sin(30)*0.7cm})}, z={({cos(70)*1cm},{sin(70)*1cm})}, line join=round, fill opacity=0.8, thick]
  
    % Draw V_0 and c
    \node at (0,1,0) {$\bullet$};
    \node at (0.3,1,0) {$V_0$};
    \node at (0.6,1,0) {$c$};
    
    % Adjust the forward slash to be more upright
    \draw[line width=0.5pt] (1.3, 0.5, -0.6) -- (1.2, 1.5, 1);
    
    % Draw V_1 and c
    \node at (1.5,1,0) {$V_1$};
    \node at (1.8,1,0) {$c$};
    
    % Draw the blue parallelogram labeled V_2 (front face of the 3D parallelogram)
    \draw[fill=blue!25!white] (2.2,0,0) -- (2.5,0,0) -- (2.5,0,1) -- (2.2,0,1) -- cycle; % Bottom face
    \node at (1.76,2.5,-0.45) {$V_2$};
    
    % Draw c
    \node at (2.5,1.3,0) {$c$};

    \node at (3.4,0,1) {$V_3$};
    
    % Draw the 3D parallelogram
    \draw[fill=blue!40!white] (3.1,0,0) -- (3.4,0,0) -- (3.4,0.7,0) -- (3.1,0.7,0) -- cycle; % Base face
    \draw[fill=blue!30!white] (3.1,0.7,0) -- (3.4,0.7,0) -- (3.4,0.7,1) -- (3.1,0.7,1) -- cycle; % Top face
    \draw[fill=blue!20!white] (3.4,0,0) -- (3.4,0,1) -- (3.4,0.7,1) -- (3.4,0.7,0) -- cycle; % Side face
    \draw[fill=blue!15!white] (3.1,0,0) -- (3.1,0,1) -- (3.1,0.7,1) -- (3.1,0.7,0) -- cycle; % Other side face
    \draw[fill=blue!25!white] (3.1,0,0) -- (3.4,0,0) -- (3.4,0,1) -- (3.1,0,1) -- cycle; % Bottom face
    \draw[fill=blue!35!white] (3.1,0.7,1) -- (3.4,0.7,1) -- (3.4,0,1) -- (3.1,0,1) -- cycle; % Rear face
    
    % Draw c and ellipsis
    \node at (3.7,1.3,0) {$c$};
    \node at (4,1.3,0) {...};

  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd use an `anchor` to align the nodes with text to the baseline. And instead of `$c$` I think it should be `$\subset$`. I'd also probably not use a 3D view, at least not for the whole drawing. But it is a nice starting point!

Comment: Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 3):

You can create a few Ti*k*Z pictures and align the `base` anchor of the text node with the baseline of the surrounding text:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\tikz[baseline=(n.base)]{
    \fill circle[radius=1pt]
        node[midway, right] (n) {$V_{0}$};
}

$\subset$

\tikz[baseline=(n.base), xslant=0.33]{
    \draw (0,-0.5) -- (0,0.5)
        node[midway, right] (n) {$V_{1}$};
}

$\subset$

\tikz[baseline=(n.base), xslant=0.33]{
    \draw[fill=blue, fill opacity=0.25] 
        (-0.5,-0.5) rectangle (0.5,0.5)
        node[midway, opacity=1] (n) {$V_{2}$};
}

$\subset$

\tikz[baseline=(n.base), xslant=0.33]{
    \path[shift={(0.25,0.25)}]
        (-0.5,-0.5) coordinate (a) 
            rectangle (0.5,0.5) coordinate (b);
    \path (-0.5,-0.5) coordinate (c) 
            rectangle (0.5,0.5) coordinate (d);
    \draw[blue!50!black, opacity=0.5] 
        (a |- b) |- (a -| b)
        (a) -- (c) (b) -- (d);
    \fill[blue, fill opacity=0.25]
        (c) -- (c |- d) -- (a |- b) -- (b) -- 
        (a -| b) -- (c -| d) -- cycle;
    \draw[fill=blue, fill opacity=0.25]
        (c) rectangle (d);
    \draw (c |- d) -- (a |- b) -- (b) -- 
        (a -| b) -- (c -| d);
    \path
        (-0.5,-0.5) -- (0.5,0.5)
        node[midway, opacity=1] (n) {$V_{3}$};
}

$\subset$

\tikz[baseline=(n.base), xslant=0.33]{
    \path[shift={(0.25,0.25)}]
        (-0.5,-0.5) coordinate (a) 
            rectangle (0.5,0.5) coordinate (b);
    \path (-0.5,-0.5) coordinate (c) 
            rectangle (0.5,0.5) coordinate (d);
    \path[shift={(0.25,0.25)}]
        (-0.25,-0.25) coordinate (e) 
            rectangle (0.25,0.25) coordinate (f);
    \path (-0.25,-0.25) coordinate (g) 
            rectangle (0.25,0.25) coordinate (h);
    \draw[blue!50!black, opacity=0.5] 
        (a |- b) |- (a -| b)
        (a) -- (c) (b) -- (d)
        (e) rectangle (f)
        (g) rectangle (h)
        (e |- f) -- (g |- h)
        (e -| f) -- (g -| h)
        (e) -- (g) (f) -- (h)
        (a |- b) -- (e |- f)
        (a -| b) -- (e -| f)
        (c |- d) -- (g |- h)
        (c -| d) -- (g -| h);
        % omitting some edges as they are invisible due to perspective
    \fill[blue, fill opacity=0.25]
        (c) -- (c |- d) -- (a |- b) -- (b) -- 
        (a -| b) -- (c -| d) -- cycle;
    \draw[fill=blue, fill opacity=0.25]
        (c) rectangle (d);
    \draw (c |- d) -- (a |- b) -- (b) -- 
        (a -| b) -- (c -| d);
    \path
        (-0.5,-0.5) -- (0.5,0.5)
        node[midway, opacity=1] (n) {$V_{4}$};
}

$\subset \quad \cdots$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 :-) Love the depiction of V_4.